# The specified installation folder is read-only Netbeans error message

Tags: java, installation, netbeans, jrepl

I am trying to install Netbeans latest version. And I can't pass through this error "The specified installation folder is read-only" when it asks for "JDK for Netbeans IDE". I've tried manually unchecked the Read-only check in Program Files/Java/jdk-15/ but when it itself checks it back to Read-only. i.e. I can't unchecked the read-only option either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue before that, saying jdk is not instaled.

So i had opened cmd got to downloads folder

"netbeans name.exe" --extract

java -jar bundle.jar got the install process runing,

when i got to the folder selection page, that message apeared

Did the same process runnig cmd as admin, it worked